# Using Angular 6 web components

Tags: angular, element, angular6, angular-elements

I have the following problem. I have an application constructed using Angular 6 with routing system. I want to create a web component that will contain this application and be able to use it as part on a different web application. I have followed this tutorial and I have modify it based on my needs: https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6/

The result is that nothing renders on the screen and now error exist in the browser `Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements`.

On the browser source files I can confirm that the js file that contains my web component is loaded successfully.

Here is what I have:

In app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    VideoRoomComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    StreamComponent,
    DialogNicknameComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    DialogExtensionComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogNicknameComponent,
    DialogExtensionComponent,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}, MyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('myElement', el);
  }
}
```

Here, my index.html to test the custom element

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>My webpage!</title>
  <script>
    var global = global || window;
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myElement.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <myElement></myElement>    
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions on this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you reproduce this on StackBlitz? I've tried, but I'm not getting the specific error that *app-root* didn't match any elements.

Comment: @CSantos did you find any solution to this??

Answer (score 5):

Try using `<my-element>` instead of `<myElement>`. Also, adjust your `customElements.define` call to `customElements.define('my-element', el);`. If I'm not mistaken, to separate custom elements from native browser elements, every custom element is required to have at least one dash.  HTML is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this in your *main.ts* file.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';

import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
   entryComponents: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule
   ],
   providers: []
})
export class AppModule {
   constructor(private injector: Injector) {
      const firstComponent = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector });
      customElements.define('name-of-your-component', firstComponent);
   }

   ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

So basically you have to declare the custom element before bootstrapping your component.

Checkout this [article](https://medium.com/@neckster/how-to-build-real-web-components-with-angular-6-ac842c9062dd) for step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

you should comment youre bootstrap:[AppComponent] line before building, so it won't be bootstrapt with youre custome elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML should be like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My webpage!</title>
        <script>var global = global || window;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myElement.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <my-element></my-element>    
    </body>
</html>
```

And update app.module.ts with this.

```
customElements.define('my-element', el);
```

Read more information from [here](https://frontendguider.com/854/web-components-in-angular/).